# How to remove cloud icon in list view on CarPlay?

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

Does anyone know how to remove the little cloud icon from the list view on CarPlay? I included a screenshot of it. These stations only Live Stream and are not downloadable. I also included the code to my Carplay-AppDelegate, CarPlay-Playlist & CarPlay-StationList. Thanks

[image]

CARPLAY-APPDELEGATE CODE:

```
import Foundation
import MediaPlayer

extension AppDelegate {

    func setupCarPlay() {
        playableContentManager = MPPlayableContentManager.shared()

        playableContentManager?.delegate = self
        playableContentManager?.dataSource = self

        stationsViewController?.setupRemoteCommandCenter()
        stationsViewController?.updateLockScreen(with: nil)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MPPlayableContentDelegate {

    func playableContentManager(_ contentManager: MPPlayableContentManager, initiatePlaybackOfContentItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

            if indexPath.count == 2 {
                let station = self.carplayPlaylist.stations[indexPath[1]]
                self.stationsViewController?.selectFromCarPlay(station)
            }
            completionHandler(nil)

            // Workaround to make the Now Playing working on the simulator:
            // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818170/handling-playback-events-in-carplay-with-mpnowplayinginfocenter
            // UIApplication.shared.endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
            // UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        }
    }

    func beginLoadingChildItems(at indexPath: IndexPath, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        carplayPlaylist.load { error in
            completionHandler(error)
        }
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MPPlayableContentDataSource {

    func numberOfChildItems(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
        if indexPath.indices.count == 0 {
            return 1
        }

        return carplayPlaylist.stations.count
    }

    func contentItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> MPContentItem? {

        if indexPath.count == 1 {
            // Tab section
            let item = MPContentItem(identifier: "Stations")
            item.title = "Stations"
            item.isContainer = true
            item.isPlayable = false
            item.artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "carPlayTab").size, requestHandler: { _ -> UIImage in
                return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "carPlayTab")
            })
            return item
        } else if indexPath.count == 2, indexPath.item < carplayPlaylist.stations.count {

            // Stations section
            let station = carplayPlaylist.stations[indexPath.item]

            let item = MPContentItem(identifier: "\(station.name)")
            item.title = station.name
            item.subtitle = station.desc
            item.isPlayable = true
            item.isStreamingContent = true

            if station.imageURL.contains("http") {
                ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(urlString: station.imageURL) { image, _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        guard let image = image else { return }
                        item.artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { _ -> UIImage in
                            return image
                        })
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if let image = UIImage(named: station.imageURL) ?? UIImage(named: "stationImage") {
                    item.artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { _ -> UIImage in
                        return image
                    })
                }
            }

            return item
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

CARPLAY-PLAYLIST CODE:

```
import Foundation

class CarPlayPlaylist {

    var stations = [RadioStation]()

    func load(_ completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

        DataManager.getStationDataWithSuccess() { (data) in

            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            do {
                let jsonDictionary = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [RadioStation]].self, from: data)
                if let stationsArray = jsonDictionary["station"] {
                    self.stations = stationsArray
                }
            } catch (let error) {
                completion(error)
                return
            }

            completion(nil)
        }

    }

}
```

CARPLAY-STATIONLIST CODE:

```
import UIKit

extension StationsViewController {
    func selectFromCarPlay(_ station: RadioStation) {
        radioPlayer.station = station
        handleRemoteStationChange()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The presence of the cloud icon is depending on the value of `isStreamingContent`.

Comment: Correct, if you set it to isStreamingContent  = false then it will hide that cloud icon